# Attach Images by coordinates from filename in AutoLISP

Tags: autocad, autolisp

In AutoCad I try to batch insert images from a folder.

The filename contains the x and y coordinates.

`f.ex. "0053-0068.jpg" -> x = 53000, y = 68000`

As input I have a list with all the filenames (path included):

`f.ex. "C:\Pictures\0053-0068.jpg"`

1. How do I extract the coordinates from the string?
2. How do I attach the pictures?

```
(defun c:loadimages ()
  
  ; [...] load list (implemented and working correctly)

  (foreach img lst ; img = "C:\Pictures\0053-0068.jpg"

    (setq x ?  ) ; x = 53000.0
    (setq y ?  ) ; y = 68000.0
    (setq z 0.0) ; z = const.

    (setq scl 1000.0) ; scl = const.
    (setq ang    0.0) ; ang = const.

    (command "_IMAGE" "_ATTACH" (strcat "img1=" img) '(x y z) scl ang)
  )
  (princ)
)
(princ)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find the position of "-" in the file name with `vl-string-search` (or `vl-string-position`) to split this string and then use `atof`.

```
(foreach img lst
(setq base (vl-filename-base img)
  pos  (vl-string-search "-" base)
)
(setq x (* 1000. (atof (substr base 1 pos))))
(setq y (* 1000. (atof (substr base (+ 2 pos)))))
(setq z 0.0) ; z = const.

(setq scl 1000.0) ; scl = const.
(setq ang    0.0) ; ang = const.

(command "_IMAGE" "_ATTACH" (strcat "img1=" img) (list x y z) scl ang)
```

)